# Unable to find requested .Net framework data provider. It may not be installed

Tags: c#

I am using VS2010 Express and trying to create a new connection with the help of server explorer. i selected the server name and windows authentication.
After it i mentioned the name of database to be connected with and tested connection successfully but as i click on ok it shows me error
"Unable to find requested .Net framework data provider.It may not be installed"
i have all the required dll's in my reference of project such as system.data,system.data.entity but still it is giving error somebody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your config file...Check your config files for self terminating nodes.